# Function returning Null along with other unexpected expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, return-value

When I use some function, at the end along with the output I get some NULLs returned that I don't understand the reason for and are highly undesirable.
For example, when I define the reversal of list with

```
ReverseList[ele_List] := Module[{list = List[], i, k = 1},
  {For[i = Length[ele], i > 0, {i--, k++}, {AppendTo[list, ele[[i]]]}],
   Print[list],
   Return[list]}
  ]
```

The output I get

```
 ReverseList[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

is

```
{5,4,3,2,1} {Null, Null, Return[{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}]}
```

I am also have a problem with returning the list. Can someone please help me with these two problems?

Comment: I'm assuming this is just a toy example, but in case you weren't aware, there's also `Reverse@list`

Comment: I was just practicing with syntax to be familiar with..

Comment: Only module parameters need to be presented as a list, not the body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I understand what your trouble might be. Here is your code:

[image]

`a := b` means that the left-hand-side is a pattern and the right-hand-side should be evaluated when that pattern is found (roughly speaking). The right-hand-side in this case is:

[image]

Your function in essence **returns the entire module**. You can see this by changing `Module` to something else, like `PretendModule`:

[image]

The point is that Mathematica is a language where everything is an expression and **everything automatically returns something**. In other words, you almost never need to use `Return`.

So your function automatically "returns" the entire `Module`. But in this case, `Module` itself does its own stuff, and returns its body after it has done its variable stuff:

[image]

As you can see, the body is a list. This `Module` will return that list because that's its body and that's Module's job. However, I see what you are trying to do here. You don't need to wrap things in lists because when you use `;`, expressions are automatically combined. Run `FullForm[Hold[Print[1]; Print[2]]]` and you will get:

```
Hold[CompoundExpression[Print[1], Print[2]]]
```

So `;` is syntactic sugar for `CompoundExpression`. That's why you don't need to wrap things in lists. The operator `;` automatically combines separate expressions into single expressions. The compound expression itself will return the last expression's value when it is evaluated. So your code can be changed to:

```
ReverseList[ele_List] := Module[{list = List[], i, k = 1},
  For[i = Length[ele], i > 0, i--; k++, AppendTo[list, ele[[i]]]];
  list]
```

Comment: Good explanation!

Comment: I agree.  This is an excellent answer and worthy of reference.   Please consider posting a generic form of this answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard might literally take me a couple weeks, but will do

Answer (score 4):

`Print` returns `Null`, and you're returning a list of values, some of which are also `Null`. So:

```
ReverseList[ele_List] := 
 Module[{list = List[], i, k = 1},
     For[
       i = Length[ele], i > 0, {i--, k++},
       {AppendTo[list, ele[[i]]]}];
     Print[list];
    list]
```

would be slightly better, perhaps?

(Obviously you wouldn't really reverse a list like this, but I presume you know that...)

Slightly more idiomatic than `For` and more generally useful is `Table`:

```
ReverseList[l_List] := 
 Module[{list = l}, Table[Part[list, i], {i,  Length[list], 1, -1}]]
```

Comment: ya m just trying to be familiar with syntax

Comment: shall I always put ; instead of , in functions ?

Comment: [Essential reading](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)!