# Help with functions in Mathematica

Tags: functions, core-language

I'd like to make a function that has many parts. Doing this in something such as Java, which I am familiar with, would be simple. In *Mathematica* I have these "pieces", which I want to put into a single function:

```
(* These are just example values for testing. *)
m = 2;
portionOfPT = "friday";
portionOfCT = "pqcfku";

(* I want all of this to happen within the function. *)
ptBlocks = Partition[stringToNumbers[portionOfPT], m]
ctBlocks = Partition[stringToNumbers[portionOfCT], m]
ctMatrix = {ctBlocks[[1]], ctBlocks[[2]]}
ptMatrix = {ptBlocks[[1]], ptBlocks[[2]]}
inversePTMatrix = Inverse[ptMatrix, Modulus -> 26]

(* This is what I want to return.*)
key = Mod[inversePTMatrix.ctMatrix, 26]
```

The function would be something like this with two parameters:

```
autoPTAtkHill[portionOfPT_, portionOfCT_, m_] :=
```

How do I go about making a function containing multiple parts like this that depend on what is returned from the previous.

EDIT:

Does this look correct, and by correct I mean proper. It gives the correct results.

```
autoPTAtkHill[portionOfPT_, portionOfCT_, m_] := 
  Module[{key},
   ptBlocks = Partition[stringToNumbers[portionOfPT], m];
   ctBlocks = Partition[stringToNumbers[portionOfCT], m];
   ctMatrix = {ctBlocks[[1]], ctBlocks[[2]]};
   ptMatrix = {ptBlocks[[1]], ptBlocks[[2]]};
   inversePTMatrix = Inverse[ptMatrix, Modulus -> 26];
   key = Mod[inversePTMatrix.ctMatrix, 26]
  ];
```

Comment: Remember that a comment in Mathematica is `(*...*)` ,not `//` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Syntax.html

Comment: Check the documentation on `Module`.

Comment: My mistake, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me into the correct direction with Module. Could you check my edit and tell me if it is the way others would expect the function to look.

Comment: What is the definition of `stringToNumbers`?

Comment: minor point, but there is no purpose here to assigning the symbol `key`. Your `Mod` expression will be returned by the function without it. also `ptBlocks,ctBlocks` etc probably ought to be put in the Module scope unless of course you want them available later as a side effect.

Comment: @m_goldberg - I'm guessing `ToCharacterCode`? Connor, you might not need your own function for this.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
autoPTAtkHill[portionOfPT_, portionOfCT_, m_] := 
  Module[{ptBlocks, ctBlocks, ctMatrix, ptMatrix, inversePTMatrix},
   ptBlocks = Partition[stringToNumbers[portionOfPT], m];
   ctBlocks = Partition[stringToNumbers[portionOfCT], m];

   ctMatrix = {ctBlocks[[1]], ctBlocks[[2]]};
   ptMatrix = {ptBlocks[[1]], ptBlocks[[2]]};

   inversePTMatrix = Inverse[ptMatrix, Modulus -> 26];
   Mod[inversePTMatrix.ctMatrix, 26]];
```

As @george2079 says, the last statement in the Module is implicitly returned, so you don't need to assign it. I recommend reading my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/function-returning-null-along-with-other-unexpected-expressions/25513#25513) to clarify what exactly is going on here (it's very important).

---

By the way, instead of `{ctBlocks[[1]], ctBlocks[[2]]}` you can do `Take[ctBlocks,2]` or `ctBlocks[[1;;2]]`.

---

One thing to recognize is that there isn't any limit to what you can put inside `Module`. You can make functions scoped within the `Module`, for example:

```
f[a_] := Module[{innerF},
  innerF[n_] := n + 2;

  innerF[a + 2]];
```

For this matter, `Module` is its own thing:

```
Module[{innerF},
  innerF[n_] := n + 2;

  innerF[10]]
```

And not necessary to create a function:

```
f[a_] := (
  var1 = 1;
  var2 = 2;
  a + var1 + var2
);
```

`Module` is used to limit the scope of variables.

---

An idiom I sometimes use is something like this:

```
autoPTAtkHill[portionOfPT_, portionOfCT_, m_] := 
  Module[{partition, firstTwo, inverse, process, ctMatrix, inversePTMatrix},

   partition = Partition[#, m] &;
   firstTwo = Take[#, 2] &;
   inverse = Inverse[#, Modulus -> 26] &;

   process = RightComposition[{stringToNumbers, partition, firstTwo}];

   ctMatrix = process[portionOfCT];
   inversePTMatrix = inverse[process[portionOfPT]];

   Mod[inversePTMatrix.ctMatrix, 26]];
```

Which is useful if your algorithm has more complicated steps. There are quite a few functions like `RightComposition`. This however is not a very common idiom and might actually be harder to read for some people, the fools.

---

Finally, you can do things like this:

```
Module[{expensiveToCompute},
 expensiveToCompute = expensiveComputation[blah, blah, blah];

 myFunction[a_, b_] := Module[{},
   expensiveToCompute * etc
   ]]
```

Where `expensiveToCompute` is computed only once yet its value is hidden and only available to `myFunction` (within reason). Because `myFunction` is not shadowed by the outer Module, it's available in the global scope.