# Why do I get the Null when I evaluate Print[x] // InputForm?

Tags: core-language, output

When I execute:

```
Print[x]//InputForm
```

I get a `Null` at the last line of the result.

This is an example shown in the documentation of `Print` command in [the Mathematica's official web page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html#9078).

What is the `Null`? Why does it appear?

Comment: Because that *is* what `Print` returns. The *printed* output is a side-effect.

Comment: Use `Echo[]` if you want the output to be the expression in addition to the printing.

Comment: @ciao OK. Why do you know is the specification of `Print` so? Why did Wolfram people make `Print` so?

Comment: @TaikiBessho - (1) Because it's stated in the documentation, (2) It makes sense: What would you have it do with say `Print["one",1,"two"]`? The argument is certainly not itself a valid MMA input, so returning it as such just would not make sense.

Comment: @ciao while `Null` ref page says it is an indication of a result absence, the ref page of `Print` says only things like `Print sends its output to the channel $Output.` - which isn't clear for newbies. There are a lot of examples of strage code with `Print` statements instead of `Table` etc, and I believe it's because its purpose is not well documented.

Comment: @Kuba - Take it up with Stephen W.. Forewarning: he's a big guy, with trained and vicious Turing machines caged and ready to attack... along with the superpower to materialize 6kg books at will to fling at you...

Comment: Related:  [(25507)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25507/121), [(41086)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41086/121).  Tangentially related: [(5682)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5682/121), [(18617)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/121)

Comment: @Ciao Those are cellular automata. They snack on Turing machines.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - I've heard he uses both. Do tell, is the rumor true that Stephen was considering a name change to use the integration symbol to be read as "the genius formerly known as Stephen"?

Comment: This question was one vote away from being closed as "a simple mistake -- or easily found in the documentation."  I chose instead to close it as a duplicate because I feel this is more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mathematica is a term rewriting system.  It works by taking an input expression and transforming it according to some rules to produce an output expression.  The implication is that *every evaluation will have a result*.  For every input there is an output.

[`Null`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Null.html) is simply the expression used to represent "no result".  In StandardForm and OutputForm it is not printed.  Thus when the result is `Null`, it is usually simply not shown.  Try evaluating `Null` alone and it will appear that there is no output.  In InputForm however it is shown as "`Null`".  You can also try `InputForm[Null]`.

---

Clarification: When you evaluate `Print[x] // InputForm`, `Null` is not "the last line of the result".  It is *the only result*.  There is always precisely one result.

The `x` you see is not a result of the evaluation.  It simply happens to be shown as a side effect of evaluating `Print`.  But it is not what `Print` evaluates to and cannot be used as an input to other functions.  It is simply *displayed* when `Print` is evaluated.