# why does this function fail to return?

Tags: functions, scoping

I have written 2 functions to calculate the stress and strain of a material, the strain function works perfectly, but the stress function which very similar to the Strain function did not return what I expected? Could you please shed some light on this issue?

```
Strain[neuaxis_, y_] := Module[{b = 0.003,a}, a = -b / neuaxis, a*y + b];

Stress[neuaxis_, y_] = Module[{temp, res, Es = 200*10^3, fsy = 500}, temp = 
Strain[neuaxis, y] * Es res = If[temp > fsy, fsy, If[temp < -fsy, -fsy, temp]] res]
```

The function `Strain[30, 50]` gives -0.002 which is fine, but my function `Stress[30, 50]` returns me the unsatisfactory result as below:

> ```
> res$61948 If[temp$61948 > 500, fsy$61948, If[temp$61948 < -fsy$61948,
> -fsy$61948, temp$61948]]
> ```

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the `res = If[...]` statement. As a matter of fact, you really don't need the `res` variable at all, since `If` returns a value.

Comment: `Strain[neuaxis_, y_] := 
  Module[{b = 0.003, a}, a = -b/neuaxis; a*y + b];

Stress[neuaxis_, y_] := 
 Module[{temp, res, Es = 200*10^3, fsy = 500}, 
  temp = Strain[neuaxis, y]*Es; 
  res = If[temp > fsy, fsy, If[temp < -fsy, -fsy, temp]] ; res]`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(25507)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25507/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors. It should be

```
Strain[neuaxis_, y_] := Module[{b = 0.003, a}, a = -b/neuaxis; a*y + b]

Stress[neuaxis_, y_] := 
  Module[{temp, Es = 200*10^3, fsy = 500}, 
  temp = Strain[neuaxis, y]*Es;
  If[temp > fsy, fsy, If[temp < -fsy, -fsy, temp]]]
```

but I would write

```
With[{b = 0.003}, Strain[neuaxis_, y_] := b (1 - y/neuaxis)]

With[{Es = 200*10^3, fsy = 500},
  Stress[neuaxis_, y_] := Clip[Es Strain[neuaxis, y], {-fsy, fsy}]]
```

which will give the same results with much simpler code.

Comment: Thanks @m_goldberg for the suggestion, definitely it is much clearer than my original code. (I am a very newbie to Mathematica). Thanks !