# NullReturn from list building module

Tags: list-manipulation

This is similar to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25507/function-returning-null-along-with-other-unexpected-expressions), but I'm still having issues. I've written a function that makes a list of 3D vectors with every combination of of numbers up to a given value `n`.

```
BuildSet1[n_] := Module[{combos, list, place},
  combos = n^3;
  place = 1;
  list = Table[0, combos];
  For[x = 1, x < n + 1, x++,
   For[y = 1, y < n + 1, y++,
    For[z = 1, z < n + 1, z ++,
     list[[place]] = {x, y, z};
     place++]]];
  Return[list]]
```

Which returns for n=2: `Null Return[{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 
    1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}]`

Now for sanity I immediately wrote another function:

```
test[a_] := Module[{b},
  b = {0};
  b[[1]] = a;
  Return[b]]
```

which returns for n=2: `{2}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `list = Table[0, {combos}];`

Comment: Isn't Mathematica giving you a syntax warning? It is interpreting your code as `For[..]; * Return[b]`, and it usually gives a warning when it does this. Also, try not to use `Return`, as it is completely superfluous here, and in general `Return` does not always behave in a way that you might expect. Finally, it is much simpler to use `Tuples[{1,2}, 3]`.

Comment: @Manuel--Moe--G. There is nothing wrong with `list = Table[0, combos]`

Comment: Why not make use of the power of Mathematica, rather than trying to do it by brute force. I suggest you try `buildSet[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Tuples[Range[n], 3]`

Comment: As for what's wrong with your code, beside being inefficient, I don't thing there is anything wrong with it. When I run it, it works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there isn't really any serious correctness issue with the OP's code and, therefore, no real question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code works. There are few things about it that I find too ugly to look at, so I would at least rewrite it as

```
buildSet[n_Integer /; n > 0] :=
  Module[{list, place, x, y, z},
    place = 1;
    list = Table[0, n^3];
    For[x = 1, x < n + 1, x++,
      For[y = 1, y < n + 1, y++,
        For[z = 1, z < n + 1, z++, list[[place++]] = {x, y, z}]]];
    list]

buildSet[3]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1}, 
>  {1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, 
>  {2, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {2, 3, 3}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 3}, 
>  {3, 2, 1}, {3, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 1}, {3, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 3}}
> ```

We're talking only correctness up to now. If we add conciseness and efficiency to the discussion, then I would recommend

```
buildSet[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Tuples[Range[n], 3]
```

as a major improvement.